# Heroku "Application error" when deploying Flask app

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy a starter Flask app to Heroku. The build and deployment are successfull, without any error. The app runs without any issues on localhost. However, when I try to view my app on the heroku link, I get `Application error`.

This is my `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('layout.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

My 'requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-MySQL==1.4.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
passlib==1.7.1
pbr==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.2
scikit-learn==0.18.1
six==1.11.0
stevedore==1.28.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.2
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.5
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.1
```

And finally, the log after commiting and pushing to heroku:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 285 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 61M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://[page-name].herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/[page-name].git
   a236214..2471880  master -> master
```

Any ideas on how to proceed since I do not have any type of errors?

Comment: check `heroku logs`

Comment: @marmeladze After running `heroku logs`, I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After running `heroku logs` in `Git Bash` on `marmeladze`'s suggestion, I located the issue.

The issue was with these lines:

```
def index():
    return render_template('layout.html')
```

I changed it to return only a string (e.g `return "Hello, world"`) and it managed to deploy succesfully.

I guess I have some an error when importing / including my templates.

Answer (score 0):

you must add directiory location name in next app variable, example: app = Flask(**name**, template_folder='templates')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port details in your Procfile to establish connection from your app.

Change the command to this -> web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app

Refer this doc for more details !

https://dev.to/guptaniharika/deploying-flask-app-on-heroku-using-github-50nh